# Нужен перевод подсказки для вкладки "Отслеживаемые"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При навидении курсора на вкладку "Отслеживаемые" появляется не переведённая подсказка:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод уже был сделан недавно.

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14857

Надо дождаться подхватывания и пересборки. Текущая версия rev 2020.9.18.37632

Не забывайте, что любой участник может сам предложить перевод на https://ru.traducir.win